# Generic extension method resolution fails

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, overload-resolution

The following program does not compile, because in the line with the error, the compiler chooses the method with a single `T` parameter as the resolution, which fails because the `List<T>` does not fit the generic constraints of a single `T`. The compiler does not recognize that there is another method that could be used. If I remove the single-`T` method, the compiler will correctly find the method for many objects.

I've read two blog posts about generic method resolution, one from JonSkeet [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/) and another from Eric Lippert [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520145938/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx), but I could not find an explanation or a way to solve my problem.

Obviously, having two methods with different names would work, but I like the fact that you have a single method for those cases.

```
namespace Test
{
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  public interface SomeInterface { }

  public class SomeImplementation : SomeInterface { }

  public static class ExtensionMethods
  {
    // comment out this line, to make the compiler chose the right method on the line that throws an error below
    public static void Method<T>(this T parameter) where T : SomeInterface { }

    public static void Method<T>(this IEnumerable<T> parameter) where T : SomeInterface { }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var instance = new SomeImplementation();
      var instances = new List<SomeImplementation>();

      // works
      instance.Method();
      
      // Error  1   The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.SomeImplementation>'
      // cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
      // 'Test.ExtensionMethods.Method<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion
      // from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.SomeImplementation>' to 'Test.SomeInterface'.
      instances.Method();

      // works
      (instances as IEnumerable<SomeImplementation>).Method();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `instances.Method<SomeImplementation>();`?

Comment: @Dmitry that would indeed work. I'll test a few things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method resolution says that [closer is better](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/). See the blog post for exact rules.

What does the closer mean? Compiler will see if it can find exact match, if it can't find for some reason it will find next possible compatible methods and so forth.

Let's first make that method compile by removing the `SomeInterface` constraint.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Method<T>(this T parameter) //where T : SomeInterface
    { }

    public static void Method<T>(this IEnumerable<T> parameter) //where T : SomeInterface 
    { }
}
```

Now compiler is happy to compile, and do note that both method calls Goes to `Method(T)` rather than `Method(IEnumerable<T>)`. Why is that?

Because `Method(T)` is closer in the sense that can take any type as the parameter and also it doesn't require any conversion.

> Why is `Method(IEnumerable<T>)` not closer?

It is because you have the compile time type of the variable as `List<T>`, so it needs a reference conversion from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`. Which is closer but far from doing no conversions at all.

Back to your question.

> Why `instances.Method();` doesn't compile?

Again, as said earlier to use `Method(IEnumerable<T>)` we need some reference conversion, so obviously that's not closer. Now we're left with only one method which is very closer is `Method<T>`. But the problem is you have constrained it with `SomeInterface` and clearly `List<SomeImplementation>()` is not convertible to `SomeInterface`.

The problem is (am guessing) checking for generic constraints happens after the compiler chooses the closer overload. That invalidates the chosen best overload in this case.

You could easily fix it by changing the static type of the variable to `IEnumerable<SomeImplementation>` that will work and now you know why.

```
IEnumerable<SomeImplementation> instances = new List<SomeImplementation>();
```

Comment: Ok, that doesn't actually solve my problem (I'll still have to give a different name so people can use it without surprises), but at least it's a pretty good explanation *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing the first one without generics, as it should behave the same:

```
public static void Method(this SomeInterface parameter) { /*...*/ }
```

Or, as Dmitry suggested, by calling the second one the following way:

```
instances.Method<SomeImplementation>();
```

But here you need to add the `<SomeImplementation>` to every call...

Comment: Thats a good idea. Maybe I should have expanded my example. In our real project T is constrained to implementing *two* different interfaces, which is the reason we are using generics.

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case my idea does not work (but would work for this case - just tested it)...

Comment: I tried a lot of things and couldn't get it to work with generics in both cases without additional code calling the method either and IMO it should work - maybe someone else can shed some light on this behaviour (or it may really is a bug in the method resolution)...

Answer (score 1):

1. While I know you dont want it, I think you should really re-think if method names should be the same. I cannot see how the same name can act on an instance, and collection of such instances. For eg, if your method name is `Shoot` for `T`, then the other method should sound like `ShootThemAll` or something similar.
2. Or else you should make your assignment slightly different:

   ```
   IEnumerable<SomeImplementation> instances = new List<SomeImplementation>();
   instances.Method(); //now this should work
   ```
3. As a last option, as Dimitry says in comments you have to explicitly specify the type argument.

   ```
   instances.Method<SomeImplementation>();
   ```