# C# more specific version on generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following function

```
public static T Translate<T>(T entity)
{
    ....
}
```

Now if T is en IEnumerable<> I want to have a different behaviour so I made a second function

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Translate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    ....
}
```

When I invoke it like this

```
IEnumerable<string> test = new List<string>().AsEnumerable();
Translate(test);
```

However when I invoke it like this

```
Func<IEnumerable<string>> func = () => new List<string>().AsEnumerable();
Translate(func.Invoke())
```

It goes to the first one.
Why does this happen and what is the best construction to solve this?

### UPDATE

I build a new example with the problem

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<IEnumerable<string>> stringFunction = () => new List<string>().AsEnumerable();
    InvokeFunction(ExtendFunction(stringFunction));
}

private static T Convert<T>(T text) where  T : class 
{
    return null;
}

private static IEnumerable<T> Convert<T>(IEnumerable<T> text)
{
    return null;
}

private static Func<T> ExtendFunction<T>(Func<T> func) where T : class 
{
    return () => Convert(func.Invoke());
}

private static T InvokeFunction<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return func.Invoke();
}
```

The first function gets invoken now when I expect the second to be invoked.

Comment: best contruction maybe to turn the `IEnumerable` one into an extension method so it is clearer that you are trying to invoke that specific one - Removed the first part of my comment after looking at documentation and finding it wrong, it sounds more like not recognised type at compile time

Comment: Looks like a bug in the .net compiler.

Comment: **No** it calls second version for me in both the tests. c# 5.0 compiler with .net 4.5

Comment: Can't reproduce. Second method is invoked in both cases.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this with .NET 4.5, C# 5. It goes to the second one for me.

Comment: @pid That produces compiler error.

Comment: This doesn't reproduce in .NET 4.0 either.

Comment: Sorry I tried to simplify the problem for this website and it seems that by simplifying it I get the correct behaviour.

Comment: in my case .NET 4.5 both calls go to `public static IEnumerable<T> Translate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)`

Comment: In C#, the closest to specialization is to use a more-specific overload; however this works only when the type is know at compile time. In your case the type is decided at run time with `func.Invoke()`. If you add this line in your main method you'll get the second function called. `Convert(text: new List<string>().AsEnumerable());` this is because the type is know at compile time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to either add a second overload of `ExtendFunction`:

```
private static Func<IEnumerable<T>> ExtendFunction<T> (Func<IEnumerable<T>> func) where T : class
{
    return () => Convert(func.Invoke());
}
```

Or make the first overload invoke `Convert` method dynamically:

```
private static Func<T> ExtendFunction<T> (Func<T> func) where T : class
{
    return () => Convert((dynamic)func.Invoke());
}
```

The reason is that your `ExtendFunction` method chooses `Convert` method at compile time. You can avoid that be either adding a second overload of `ExtendFunction` which chooses the `Convert` method you need, or by moving the choice of `Convert` method to run time.

Comment: Yes, it's compile time vs. runtime issue. OP has `ExtendFunction` with `Func<T>`, so the compiler cannot know that `T` will be of type `IEnumerable<T>` (the only constraint is `where T : class`). Can also be fixed by making `ExtendFunction` use `Func<IEnumerable<T>>` instead.

Comment: you said either, if I only add `(dynamic)` casting to existing `Func<T> ExtendFunction` without adding overload `Func<IEnumerable<T>> ExtendFunction`, it still goes to first method `static T Convert`

Comment: The dynamic method seems the way to go for me however if I try it, it does not work. It still goed to the first function?

Comment: @Vogabe Well, now the issue from the question [Generic extension method resolution fails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23217585/293099), which was mentioned below, becomes important, because `T` is preffered over `IEnumerable<T>` when passing `List<T>`. You can replace `AsEnumerable()` with `Select(x => x)` to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the closest to specialization is to use a more-specific overload; however this works only when the type is know at compile time.
 
In your case the type is decided at run time because of `IEnumerable<T>`, but the compiler cannot guarantee that it will be `IEnumerable<T>`. 
If you add this line in your main method you'll get the second function called.
 `Convert(text: new List<string>().AsEnumerable());` 

this is because the type is know at compile time

so try your Main in this way and look the differences

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Func<IEnumerable<string>> stringFunction = () => new List<string>().AsEnumerable();
   InvokeFunction(ExtendFunction(stringFunction));//first function invoked
   Convert(text: new List<string>().AsEnumerable());//second function invoked
}
```

Comment: The return type of `func.Invoke()` is known at compile time. But at compile time it is `T` (`where T : class`) and not `IEnumerable<T>`. The concrete type of `T` might be `IEnumerable<T>`, but the compiler cannot guarantee that.

Comment: @knittl Thanks, I'll try to explain it in a better way

Answer (score -1):

I had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217585/generic-extension-method-resolution-fails) a few weeks ago. You can solve this by specifying the type explicitely on calling the method but that's not really worth it, because it means everybody using your methods have to know about this fact.

We solved our problem by actually giving the method another name. In your case, that would be a second method named:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TranslateAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
```

Comment: But.. This is not extension method and also we can't reproduce the problem though.

Comment: Well, an extension method is just a method. The problem that the "wrong" method is picked is still the same, regardless of `this` keyword in his or my signature. If you cannot reproduce in VS2013 that's great. I can assure you it's reproducable in VS2012.

Comment: FYI am using VS2012 only. Can't able to reproduce. Also your linked question seems to be a different problem which I'll try to answer in a moment.

Comment: @nvoigt What does the VS version have to do with anything? it varies based on the target .NET framework version.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I agree with you VS is not relevant here and also target framework is also not relevant. it is purely dependent on c# compiler and compiler alone.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel If you can find a good answer, I'd be more than happy to be proven wrong here :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, that's unlikely to be true. AFAIK VS2012 only uses c#5.0 compiler for whatever target framework and that applies for all. Do you have any reference to what you have said?

Comment: I've answered your linked question, take a look at it and let me know if am missing something. FWIW I didn't downvoted your answer.