# Why does SubscribeOn does not work here as a extension method but as a direct call?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, resharper, extension-methods, system.reactive

I have class ObserverBase. In the Start method I subscribe to an observable, apply a transformation and a filter.

I do not understand why the usage of SubscribeOn as an extension method does not compile.
Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
public class ObserverBase<T1, T2> : IPeer<T1, T2>
{

    private readonly ISubject<T2> subject;

    private readonly IMapper<T1, T2> messageMapper;

    protected ObserverBase(ISubject<T2> subject, IMapper<T1, T2> messageMapper)
    {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.messageMapper = messageMapper;
    }

    public IObservable<T2> Start(IObservable<T1> observable, Func<T2, bool> predicate)
    {
        //works
        Synchronization.ObserveOn(Synchronization.SubscribeOn(observable, TaskPoolScheduler.Default),
                                  Scheduler.Immediate)
                  .Select(message => this.messageMapper.Map(message))
                  .Where(predicate)
                  .Subscribe(observation => this.subject.OnNext(observation));


        // compile error on SubscribeOn: The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type argument explicitly.
        observable.SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Immediate)
                  .Select(message => this.messageMapper.Map(message))
                  .Where(predicate)
                  .Subscribe(observation => this.subject.OnNext(observation));

        // compile error on TaskPoolScheduler.Default: Cannot resolve method SubscribeOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler)
        observable.SubscribeOn<T1>(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Immediate)
                  .Select(message => this.messageMapper.Map(message))
                  .Where(predicate)
                  .Subscribe(observation => this.subject.OnNext(observation));

        return this.subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"...as an extension method does not compile"* - you need to supply the compile error.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me - did you include a `using` statement for the `System.Reactive.Linq` namespace (where `SubscribeOn` is defined)? `Synchronization.ObserveOn` is in a different namespace (`System.Reactive.Concurrency`) - which I suspect you have a using statement for already.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are quite low in the chain of overload resolution: they are not "close" enough: http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/

You might found this answer useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25564127/863564 
It seems to be directly related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio compiles the code but ReSharper reported these errors. After restarting Visual Studio ReSharper stopped complaining.

Comment: Ah! Resharper... it's a love-hate relationship!

Comment: you can't live with or without it