# Why does generic interface constraint mess up the use of extension methods?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

This problem is very difficult for me to explain, so I mocked up some dummy code to show the problem I encountered. It has to do with generic constraints on extension methods. Within my extension method I need the generic class (but the example does not show this). Let's dive in:

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface IOne { }

public interface ITwo { }
```

Now I create some extension methods for them:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ParseValue(this ITwo ob)
    {
        return "Two";
    }

    public static string ParseValue<T>(this T obj) where T : class, IOne
    {
        return "One";
    }
}
```

Looks fine right? Now I create an implementation of `ITwo` and it'll get messy:

```
public class Two: ITwo
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return this.ParseValue();
    }
}
```

This class doesn't compile. I get te following error:

> The type 'GenericProblem.Two' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in
>   the generic type or method
>   'GenericProblem.Extensions.ParseValue(T)'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'GenericProblem.Two' to
>   'GenericProblem.IOne'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217585/generic-extension-method-resolution-fails). I guess this is a duplicate, isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, not sure, did you get the same error message?

Comment: From the linked question: *The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.SomeImplementation>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method..*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the error, I've [answered it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25564127/2530848).

> How can I solve this problem?

You need to cast `this` as `ITwo` type before calling `ParseValue`, otherwise compiler will not be able to choose the right match.

```
public class Two : ITwo
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return ((ITwo)this).ParseValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works! But even after reading the answer I'm still baffled as to why the compiler can't figure this one out...

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker I explained it pretty well in the linked answer, which part you don't get it? Specifically in this part I explained why it doesn't work. *The problem is (am guessing) checking for generic constraints happens after the compiler chooses the closer overload. That invalidates the chosen best overload in this case.*

Comment: I know... but I would think that this problem could be easily solved by the compiler. Because it knows it is not the right method. I'll try to fiddle around with the namespace. This might get me somewhere as these interfaces live in their own namespaces.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward to me.

In your extension class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ParseValue(this ITwo ob)
    {
        return "Two";
    }

    public static string ParseValue<T>(this T obj) where T : class, IOne
    {
        return "One";
    }
}
```

You do have the method, `ParseValue<T>` and you put a constraint on it, saying that `T` must be of type `IOne`

In your implementation of ITwo, you try to call the extension method on the object `this`.
Obvious `this` is of type `ITwo` so your extension method will not work anymore.

Just change the signature of your extension method like:

```
public static string ParseValue<T>(this T obj) where T : class, ITwo
```

That should do the trick.

**Edit:**

According to the original questioner, the solution did not compile.
Underneath is the full source code how I have it and this does compile:

```
public interface IOne { }

public interface ITwo { }

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ParseValue(this ITwo ob)
    {
        return "Two";
    }

    public static string ParseValue<T>(this T obj) where T : class, ITwo
    {
        return "One";
    }
}

public class Two : ITwo
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return this.ParseValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand it then. Maybe edit your question with a more concrete example and I'll see what I can do

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the solution. I tried it, but that doesn't compile either. I get a: Type 'GenericProblem.Extensions' already defines a member called 'ParseValue' with the same parameter types.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker Please see my updated answer. I have provided the code and can guarantee that this compiles. Just tested on my machine.

Comment: Oooow nooooo... I'm missing my dear `IOne`... was one of the best interface I ever made. Why did it need to die? Why... he shall be missed. :P

Comment: No, kicking out the `IOne` is not an option.

Comment: That's why I asked you to update the question so that it makes a bit more sense. With the question now, we don't know what the interfaces are doing and why removing one is not an option.